# Trigger a 3 V line with 12 V

Tags: led, switches, led-strip, touch

I would like to trigger a 3 V line (a push dimmer circuit) with a touch button (which is powered by 12 V).

Closing the 3 V will turn off (short press)/turn on (short press)/dim (long press) the LED strip.

Here is my complete circuit:

[image]

How can I connect the outgoing 12 V line from the touch button to close the 3 V line (the red question mark)?

Can this be realized by a transistor, optocoupler, etc.?

Hardware used:
LED controller: GLEDOPTO GL-C-013P (zigbee (3 wire/2 wire 2in1)) [LED Conttroller](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005004400974419.html)
Touch button: [Touch Button](https://de.aliexpress.com/item/1005003191400339.html)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add links to datasheets for the items "LED Controller" and "Touch button". Then we can see their specifications, so we'll be able to give you useful answers.

Comment: I have addded links to the hardware I am using. There are no specs though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the gnds of 3V and 12V are or can be connected together (not isolated), you can use a NPN transistor like 3904 with 47k in base. Otherwise you have to use an optocoupler.

[image]

Comment: I do not know if they are connected to the same GND or if the LED controller is isolating them.

Comment: Just measure the resistance with multimeter between Gnd and minus of push input.

Comment: I have used a BC547C as NPN transistor. This is working. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the voltage with a Zener diode. Put a 10 kΩ resistor in series with the Zener diode to limit the current to the Zener.
The capacitor and the second resistor will debounce the signal, avoiding erratic signals from the switch when pressing and releasing.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0JrRx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you are using a power supply with screw terminals (not plug in like on the Ali Express website), you can do the following:
Use the ground of the power supply and leave the V- not connected.
Both schematics show a touch sensor switch (with the additional ground line).

ATTENTION: Do not use the "C" connections as ground.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faoiEl.png)</sup>

Comment: I do not quite understand how to connect this. I assume the 12V is the line comming from the touch button. But what about the two 3V lines (+ and -). Is the GND the main one (from 12V) or from the LED controllers 3V?

Comment: The 3V and 12V GND should be the same in this example.

Comment: Normally the LED controller ground and the 12V supply ground should be the same. You can check it by measuring the impedance between the two grounds with a multi meter. If it's not, you will have to connect them together. But that would be very strange that they were not the same.

Comment: If you are using an inductive touch sensor, you don't need the capacitor (C1) and R2 neither but it's not bad to keep it.

Comment: I have just realized that I am not understanding GND. My LED driver (230V in / 12V out) has just a 12V + and - output connector. Is the minus 12V equal to GND?  If not, where is my GND?

Comment: Yes - or V- is equal to ground aka GND. Sometimes ground is also called COM (for "common ground") but this became less common LOL. It's very important not mix "ground" and "earth". Earth is the yellow-green wire coming from the 230V cable. Or with "neutral" which is the blue wire from the 230V cable. Ground is the negative output of the 12V output. Usually the wire for ground aka V- is black and V+ is red. Always respect colour code.

Comment: Note that on you dimmer there are "+" and "C" terminals. C is not forcibly ground (and IMO probably not). I think it works only with LED strips specifically made for this device. Be careful to make the connections correctly.

Comment: I have not tested this solution, as I already had a transistor + resistors. I appreciate the help and multiple proposals. Thank you.